# Get method data continuously without while

Tags: c#, kinect, propertychanged

I'm trying to get data from a Kinects accelerometer, but it doesn't have a change notification event, so to get the data, I'm using a while loop right now. Is there any way to bind the AccelerometerGetCurrentReading () methods result to a property and then use the propertychanged event, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

- Create a class AccelerometerReader which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
- Add a property which will represent the current (latest) value that you read from the accelerometer.
- In the property setter, let the property fire the PropertyChanged event when the value is different.
- When the class is instanced, start a task which continuously reads from the accelerometer, and sets the value in the property.
- Since the value only fires on a change, any observers are only notified whenever a change occurs.
- It is propably wise to either add a delay in your infinite loop, or add a timing mechanism so you only read it every x millisecond
- You might want to make the class disposable so you can stop your task, or stop your timer.

An example using a loop. A simple boolean is used to stop the loop, and the boolean is set when the object is disposed. **Warning: this code hasn't been tested yet!**

```
class AccelerometerReader: INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable {
    #region Constructor

    public AccelerometerReader() {
        new Task(ReadAccelerometer).Start();
    }

    #endregion
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null) {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Properties

    int _value;
    public int Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { 
            if (value != _value) {
                _value = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Accelerometer reading

    bool _stopLoop = false;

    void StartReadLoop() {
        while (!_stopLoop) {
            Value = ReadAccelerometer();
            // TODO: Delay a little
        }
    }

    int ReadAccelerometer() {
        // TODO: Read from accelerometer...
    }

    #endregion
    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose() {
        _stopLoop = true;

        // TODO: Add a proper IDisposable implementation
    }

    #endregion
}
```